# Django, al mostrar información en HTML con {% for xxx in xxx %} repite una hoja por cada respuesta

Tags: python, django

Tengo el siguiente codigo html para mostrar informacion en base a una busqueda, cuando la realizo no pone toda la informacion en una sola pagina sino que me da una respuesta por hoja, no se si el formato html este mal o el codigo para mostrar mi informacion, creo que es algo sencillo pero ya le di mil vueltas y no encuentro como solucionarlo.

```
{% for item in res %}
    <table width="1258" border="1" class="listados">
      <tr>
        <tbody>
        <td width="30"><p>1</p></td>
        <td width="250"><p>Publicacion DOF</p></td>
        <td width="250">{% if item.num_base_id == 1 %} <a href="/detalle/{{ item.Num }}"> {{item.doc}} {% else %} <a href=" ">  {% endif %}</td>
        <td width="100">{% if item.Adjunto_lop %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_lop.url }}">{{item.LOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}</td>
        <td width="100">{% if item.Adjunto_rlo %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_rlo.url }}">{{item.RLOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}</td>
        <tr></tr></td>
        <td><p>2</p></td>
        <td><p>Registro Compranet</td>
        <td>{% if item.num_base_id == 2 %} <a href="/detalle/{{ item.Num }}"> {{item.doc}} </a> 
            {% else %}
            <a href=" ">  {% endif %}
        <td>{% if item.Adjunto_lop %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_lop.url }}">{{item.LOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}
        <td>{% if item.Adjunto_rlo %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_rlo.url }}">{{item.RLOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p>3</p></td>
        <td><p>Convocatoria / Bases de Licitacion</p></td>
        <td>{% if item.num_base_id == 3 %} <a href="/detalle/{{ item.Num }}"> {{item.doc}} </a> 
          {% else %}
          <a href=" ">  {% endif %}</td>
        <td>{% if item.Adjunto_lop %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_lop.url }}">{{item.LOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}</td>
        <td>{% if item.Adjunto_rlo %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_rlo.url }}">{{item.RLOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que te repite la tabla?

Comment: Hola @KevinRamirezZavalza gracias por responder, cada registro lo pone en una hoja nueva y esta bien filtrado pero no me pone la información en una sola hoja

Comment: https://cutt.ly/amWXDpN

Answer (score 0):

pues finalmente encontre la respuesta y la dejo por si alguien mas se atora con esto, no creo que sea lo mas eficiente pero en lo que encuentro otra solucion me esta funcionando

```
    <table width="1258" border="1" class="listados">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="30">
        <p>1</p>
      </td>
      <td width="250">
        {% with desp="green" %}
        
         <p><B><FONT COLOR = {{desp}} >Publicacion DOF</FONT></p>
        
         
      
       
         
      </td>

      {% for item in res %}
      {% if forloop %}
      {% if item.num_base_id == 1 %} 
      <td width="250">{% if item.num_base_id == 1 %}<a href="/detalle/{{ item.Num }}"> {{item.doc}} {% else %} <a href=" "> {% endif %} </td>
      <td width="100">{% if item.Adjunto_lop %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_lop.url }}">{{item.LOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}</td>
      <td width="100">{% if item.Adjunto_rlo %} <a href="{{ item.Adjunto_rlo.url }}">{{item.RLOPSRMEP}}</a> {% endif %}</td>
      {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```